# Formally determining the minimum number of poles needed to realize some suggested switching arrangement

Tags: switches, switching, boolean-algebra, analysis, optimization

Many times, when designing passive switching circuits, one has the following engineering problem:

1. We know we want to have some number of switches, each with some number of throws.
2. For each possible switch combination, we know exactly how we want our circuit to look, meaning which nodes we want to be connected to/disconnected from other nodes.
3. However, we can only get switches with some max number "M" of poles, in real life.

**Question**: how can we determine, formally, if our switching arrangement is possible to implement, using only switches with no more than "M" poles?

What I am looking for are references to formal methodologies for answering this basic question. A good starting point for formalization seems to be Shannon's ["A Symbolic Analysis of Relay and Switching Circuits"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Symbolic_Analysis_of_Relay_and_Switching_Circuits), and I am wondering if it can be extended for this purpose. Are there any related papers? Or, is there some way to use Shannon's calculus for this situation?

Comment: Just use basic manual switches that activate as many relays as is needed to solve the problem.

Comment: This seems like more a question for one of the mathematics boards.

Comment: this feels NP, but I don't have the chops to prove it.

Comment: hm, could you sketch an example? I honestly think you're either asking us to help you transform the most basic boolean expressions, or you're asking us how to design essentially bit-adressable ROM.

Comment: @Jasen NP doesn't mean unsolvable.

Comment: If this type of question isn't on topic for this forum, I'm not sure what is.

Comment: Marcus, a basic example: you have a guitar with two pickups and two on/off toggle switches. You would like to rewire this so that the "off/off" position is both pickups on in series. You can only get 4PDT switches due to general availability and space constraints. Is it possible to realize your switching scheme with only 4PDT switches?

Comment: (Note - don't bother trying to solve that example for me, since I already know the answer for that particular example. That is just to show a real situation where these problems turn up. What I really need is a method to answer these questions in general.)

Comment: this is unclear ... `rewire this so that the "off/off" position is both pickups on in series` .... does it mean both pickups connected in series? .... what would be the result of both switches in the ON position?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia this is super unclear. Wiring a switch in a specific way gives it a specific meaning. I'm not sure whether I'm confused, or whether you're confusing what "in series" means, or whether you want something impossible. I think you'll have to seriously extend your question by **editing** it (don't just leave comments) and give a very specific example; avoid jargon if you're unsure about its meaning.

Comment: @jsotola: right. Both switches in "ON" is both pickups wired to the output in parallel. I chose this example as a typical modification people do to such guitars, where ON/OFF is pickup 1 only on the output, ON/ON is pickups 1&2 in parallel, and OFF/ON is pickup 2 only, and OFF/OFF is no pickups on. Many people feel like "OFF/OFF" is a useless position, so they want to change OFF/OFF be pickups 1 + 2 on the output in series instead. So then you ask, is this possible with only, let's say, 4PDT switches? In this situation the answer happens to be yes; how do you answer such questions in general?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Can you clarify what you mean by "wiring a switch in a specific way gives it a specific meaning?" What is unclear about the throwaway example I just gave -- the part about guitar pickups being wired to the output in series? I am happy to edit my question but I am not sure how to clarify my example.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia I'm really confused by what different kinds of wirings you mean; "both switches in ON is both pickups wired to the output in parallel": ok, I'm not clear what that means. Really, please just start adding to your question, with diagrams, tables, whatever makes your problem best defined.